# async AppDomain.AssemblyResolve

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, assemblyresolve

I dynamically load large assemblies from remote server in Winforms UI using AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event. Is it possible make my assembly resolve method async?

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;

Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)  // how to make it async?
{
   // some logic where I need to use await operator
}
```

Comment: Event handlers are one of the few cases where using `async void` is acceptable.

Comment: Unfortunately `AssemblyResolve` returns `Assembly` instead of `void`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible make my assembly resolve method async?

No. The event signature is synchronous, so your implementation must be synchronous. You'll need to [block on asynchronous code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development).